# Visual Studio 11: Server-side includes in ASP .NET Development Server

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ssi, asp.net-development-serv

I am testing a static website project in [VS11 beta](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/en-us) to check its capabilities to handle HTML, CSS, JS code and the great built-in browser (Page inspector) for live manipulation of the page. All those wonders I watched on a [channel 9 video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Web+Camps+TV/Web-Developer-Efficiency-Tools-in-Visual-Studio-11). 8-)

Unfortunately, my website has SSI for header, footers and common partials which VS's page inspector or any browser doesn't render at debug time. It appears to me ASP .NET Development Server has to be configured for SSI which I don't have any clue how and I can't find help anywhere. I know better way to do is to use the server-side script, but same website is already deployed on a hosting server running IIS 7.0 and working like a charm.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't run IIS on your development PC?

Comment: Andrew, of course I can install and configure it on my local box. But for a web designer working on HTML and CSS, wouldn't it make sense if the SSI is enabled in the lightweight|pre-instaled ASP.NET development server by default? Is SSI even supported in dev server?

Comment: It looks like IIS Express can do SSI: http://forums.iis.net/p/1183319/2003243.aspx . But how many features do you expect in a *lightweight* server intended for *ASP.NET* development? ;)

Comment: Well page inspector does a pretty good job for Agile development (developers and designers both). Compared to the features in the aforementioned video, I believe SSI isn't a big deal. Can you confirm if there is a way to enable it? Thank you.

Comment: No, I can't confirm that. I suppose that they had to draw the line somewhere in the features list. A quick look on google didn't suggest anything to me, I guess you've already done a more extensive search. One thing: in the link I posted earlier, the poster mentioned renaming the .html files to .aspx (with IIS Express) and SSI started working, which has to be worth a try.